# bad_any_cast exception when returning string from templated function

Tags: c++, string, templates, exception, any

I'm creating a config file parser with values stored in an unordered_map. The config values are a mixture of strings, ints, floats, and bools, so I'm using std::any to store these in an unordered map like so:

```
static unordered_map<string, any> CONFIG_VALUES =
{
    {"title",           "The window title"},
    {"xRes",            1024},
    //...
};
```

I have a generic getter function to allow retrieval of config values like so:

```
template<typename T>
T GetValue(const string& valueName) const
{
    auto result = CONFIG_VALUES.find(valueName);
    if (result != CONFIG_VALUES.end())
    {
        return any_cast<T>(result->second);
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid config key");
    }
}
```

My code compiles, and I'm able to successfully retrieve an int like so:

```
int myXres = MyConfig->GetValue<int>("xRes");
```

But, if I try and get a string:

```
string myTitle = MyConfig->GetValue<string>("title");
```

I get a crash:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF99463A799 in program.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_any_cast at memory location 0x000000DCD76FDCE8. occurred
```

In Visual Studio debugger locals I see that the std::any type of the string is

```
type    0x00007ff6950f2328 {program.exe!char const * `RTTI Type Descriptor'} {_Data={_UndecoratedName=0x0000000000000000 <NULL> ...} }
```

I suspect that the "char const *" might be the issue here (because we're passing "string" as the template parameter), but I'm not sure how to fix it... (Or, maybe this is a red herring).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what type `std::any` stores `"The window title"` as, but I don't see why it would have a preference for storing it as an `std::string`. It's probably a `const char *`. Try using `std::string("The window title")` in your map initializer.

Comment: `std::any` is a blunt instrument and often not worth the price it requires. Consider using an `std::variant` with only the types your config values could have.

Comment: Thanks - turns out, it was stored as a char const*, because as I realize now, that's what I was defining it as :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the value being a `char const*`. You'll need to store it as a `std::string` in the map, like this:

```
static unordered_map<string, any> CONFIG_VALUES =
{
    {"title",           std::string("The window title")},
    {"xRes",            1024},
    //...
};
```

Alternatively, you could do the `any_cast` to the correct type, like this:

```
string myTitle = GetValue<char const*>("title");
```

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/FbSCSK).

Comment: Can also use the std::string literal: `"The window title"s`